# GEnexus, que versión es más estable para WEB, GXvo3 u15 v/s Gx15u8

Tags: genexus

según la experiencia que tienen, ¿cual es la mejor versión de Genexus, la que da menos errores, para trabajar en aplicaciones web?.

lo pregunto ya que varios colegas de me están casi convenciendo de volver a la versión Gx3vo3 y dejar la Gx15 únicamente para desarrollo smartdevice.

es verdad que he tenido más problemas de lo normal con gx15 web,(no funcionaron los caledarios al dar click, no encontraba la libreria jquery, da error 403 sin explicación aparente...todo esto paso en GX15 pero la misma aplicación en GX3vo3 funciona sin problemas)  he ido corrigiendo todos, ya sea con códigos java nativo o librerías ".jar" de Google.

espero sus apreciaciones, para saber si el problema soy yo o a la versión de gx15 le falta estabilizarse.

gracias
saludos
Sergio

Answer (score 2):

Sin duda GeneXus 15 Upgrade 8 es mucho mejor, estable, más rápido y más seguro. De haber algún punto en el que eso no se verifique con la realidad, contacta al equipo GeneXus, pues es máxima prioridad para GeneXus que cada versión sea mejor o igual que la anterior, en todo sentido.